# How to make a file using UNICODE like Jar files?

Tags: java

I just want to know if this is possible to jar files? thanks!

Comment: You question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a text file in UNICODE to a Jar file?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know if it is possible to make the file name of a jar file in UNICODE format.thanks a lot...

Comment: I think any restrictions on file names lies in the operating system, not in java as it uses unicode internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode defines encoding of **text**. Jar is a **binary** compression/container format, so this doesn't make any sense.